# Filter out certain grpc exceptions via Envoy?

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy

I'd like to create a reverse proxy to expose several grpc backend services on one host. But I'd also like to whitelist certain grpc status exception categories, and drop all others. I think I've read somewhere that grpc exceptions go into http/2 trailers, so that might be an option.

I'm trying to find info on the grpc wire protocol for passing exceptions, but can't find anything amid all the info on protobuf itself.

Any hints/links ?

Comment: For exception whitelist, I think the interceptor of gRPC is the best choose. You can use status code in interceptor for judge which to expose.

Comment: Our backend services use the interceptor. But these backend services expose more information for internal developers than I'd like to expose to external users. That's why we want a proxy between the internet and our backend services. Now I can easily write a proxy in Go or Kotlin or whatever that does this kind of exception filtering, but it seems a bit overkill to have a whole separate application.